# Python : accessing a class variable from another module returns ''(Empty string) from imported module python

Tags: python, class, import

I am new to python OO concepts and tried to understand the below program which i need to use in my code to access one of the class variable, but the the value of the variable returns ''(Empty string) when accessing from other module. I understand that there is some error/way of using the variable in my case, so could you please let me know what is wrong in the below code and how to use it correctly.

Here are the two files with to classes.

**AA.py**

```
import BB    
class SubClass:   
    def __init__(self):
        pass    
    def operation1(self):
        sat2 = BB.Main_Class()
        print('Main Class CAR ',sat2.car)
        print('Main Class CAR ', BB.Main_Class.car)
```

**BB.py**

```
import AA    
class Main_Class:    
    car = ''    
    def __init__(self):
        pass      
    def go(self):
        Main_Class.car = 'Toyota'
        print('In BB Main_Class.car', Main_Class.car)
        nit = AA.SubClass()
        nit.operation1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sat1 = Main_Class()
    sat1.go()
    print('1 instacne',sat1.car)
    print('Class instacne',Main_Class.car)
```

the output is,

```
    ('In BB MainClass.car', 'Toyota')
    ('Main Class CAR', '')
    ('Main Class CAR', '')
    ('1 instacne', 'Toyota')
    ('Class instacne', 'Toyota')
```

Could you please let me know why the 'Main Class Car' print is ""(Empty string) instead of Toyota? Also, what could be the right way to access the value.

Comment: There is no `Null` in Python, instead it is `None`, but there are no `None`s here... Do you mean the empty string, `''`?

Comment: Yes, i meant '' empty string. Edited the question, thanks.

Comment: There's something you aren't showing us, note, `'CAR'` isn't in all caps as your print statement in `operstion1` would imply...

Comment: To post it on this forum, i just edited the prints. 100% sure except that print, everything else is same and the output is still ''. sorry for for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the `Main_Class` you are modifying in `BB.py` is not the same `Main_Class` that `AA.py` is importing because you're running `python BB.py` as the main script.

When you run a python script like this

```
python BB.py
```

Python will load that module as the `__main__` module.  It's why the `if __name__ == '__main__':` check works.  The name of that module is `__main__`, not `BB`.

Then, your `__main__` (remember, not `BB`) module imports the `AA` module, which it finds because it's in the same directory, which python automatically adds to the `PYTHONPATH`.  Then the `AA` module loads the `BB` module, *which will be imported a 2nd time as a completely different module than the `BB.py` script you ran from the command prompt*.

This is the reason why you shouldn't run your module files directly form command prompts.

You could fix this by creating a `CC.py` file and running `python CC.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import BB
    sat1 = BB.Main_Class()
    sat1.go()
    print('1 instacne', sat1.car)
    print('Class instacne', BB.Main_Class.car)
```

Comment: It worked and I undetstand it now. I could not give you up vote due to the lack of reputation score but definitely i will you one very soon. Thanks for your time.